# Limit of a particular Riemann sum

Tags: integration

I am trying to show that the limit of $\sum_{0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}$ when n approches $+∞$ is $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{t+1}dt = \ln(2)$

I think I need to use the following Riemann sum $\sum_{0}^{n} \frac{1}{k+n}$ because it has the same limit as well but I don't know whether I am doing something wrong.

Can you help me figure out how to solve this problem please?

Thanks!

EDIT : Based on your answer @user647486 I have to  do this?

[I am not very good at using LaTeX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb2k3.jpg)

However, I have difficulties justifing why I can take limits. To me it's obvious that when a n approches $+∞$ the approximation error becomes neglectible but I'm not sure whether it's a goo jsutification. I'm probably searching for something too complicated but nothing comes to mind...

Comment: Use the expansion $\frac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kx^k$. Integrating its partial sums on $[0,1]$ gives you the partial sums of the series that you want. You only need to justify why you can take limits.